# Meaning of different inequalities when testing the probabilities of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm trying to figure out what different inequalities mean when testing the probability that a random variable is greater or less than a certain value. I've been searching around but I can't seem to find any questions that ask this specifically.

Say I have a CDF, $F(y)$, defined as
$$F(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & : y \lt 0\\
y & : 0 \le y \lt 1\\
1 & : y \ge 1
\end{array}
\right.$$
along with a random variable $X$, and some value $y$. I know that:

- $P(X \le y) = F(y)$
- $P(X \gt y) = 1 - F(y)$
- $P(y_1 \lt X \le y_2) = F(y_2) - F(y_1)$

But what method would I use to find the following?

- $P(X \lt y)$
- $P(X \ge y)$
- $P(y_1 \lt X \lt y_2)$

Does the strictness of the inequality have any effect in this context?

Comment: Since $F(y)$ is continuous, $P(X=y)=0$ for any $y$, so strictness doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of the following:

- $P(X < y) = P(X \le y) - P(X=y)$
- $P(X < y) = \lim\limits_{z \uparrow y} P(X \le z)$  using the limit as $z$ approaches $y$ from below

If $X$ is a continuous random variable, i.e. the cumulative distribution function $F(y)$ is a continuous function, then $P(X=y)=0$ and $P(X < y) = P(X \le y) = F(y)$, so your second triple will have the same results as your first triple